# I need to press a specific key and have my script " GO TO" another part in the script

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, command, set, goto

I have a batch script that I desperately need help with. I use a batch script to grab files from folders and move them. The script sweeps the folders every 30 sec but you can "press a key to continue" also. I need to change it so I can press a specific key, doesn't matter what key, and have it GO TO the top location of my script to reset.

Below is a striped down version of what I currently have.

```
@echo off

set /p username=ENTER LOGIN:

echo.

:pc

echo   1 -- Flats
echo   2 -- Simple Tabletop

set /P rmFunc="Enter a choice: "
for %%I in (1 x) do if #%rmFunc%==#%%I goto run%%I

:run1
set pc=300
goto begin

:run2
set pc=400
goto begin

:begin
set studio=TT
set computer=Handbag_1
set setnumber=
set studiosetnumber=%studio%_%setnumber%
set delay_swch=5
set delay_loop=30

:bottom

echo logged in as: %username%

timeout /t %delay_loop%
GOTO BOTTOM
```

Comment: I recognize part of this code.  :)  No clue what you're asking, but I am flattered that you chose to use my menu entry method anyway.  Well, or parts of it, at least.  It seems to be missing some stuff, like a `2` in the `for %%I in (1 x)` parenthetical, a `goto pc` if the selection is not in the `for` loop of valid values, and anything to do with grabbing files and moving them.

Comment: I stripped it down to the bar bones minimum that the site would still let me post, there was much more to the script. If you copy this and run it, what I'm asking would become more clear..  The script sweeps folders every 30 seconds, moves the files, then counts down 30 sec and repeats.. I would like to be able to press ENTER or CTRL+W, etc. and have it reset the script instead of simply restarting the 30 sec countdown.   My script puts a code at the end of each file, you select the code at launch. Right now you have to close the script and relaunch to change the code.

Comment: I need it to perform just like normal but have the option to press some keyboard key, or CTRL+ a keyboard and have it go back to where you select your choice at the top..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to determine what key was pressed when using TIMEOUT, so that command is of no help.

You could use the CHOICE command with the /T (timeout) and /D (default) options instead. You can no longer simply press any key. Instead you can only press one key to restart, and another specific key to continue, or wait till the default value (continue) is returned. The biggest drawback is it no longer has a visual countdown.

```
echo Press C to Continue, or R to Restart
choice /c cr /d c /t 30 /n /m "The process will automatically continue in 30 seconds "
if errorlevel 2 goto pc
goto bottom
```

You could display a countdown timer by adding a third undocumented default option and setting the timeout to 1 second. If the default is returned, then it decrements the counter. Once the counter reaches 0 then the desired time has elapsed and you treat it as Continue.

I use the SET /P trick to display the prompt with a without a newline. I end with a carriage return so that the next prompt displays from the beginning of the same line.

The countdown timing will be a bit off, but it should be plenty good enough.

The carriage return variable must be defined and delayed expansion must be enabled near the top (before any loop label).

```
:: Define CR to hold a carriage return (0x0D)
for /f %%A in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%A"

:: Delayed expansion must be enabled to use the CR variable
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
```

The timer code then becomes

```
set wait=15
:waitLoop
<nul set /p ="Press C to Continue, or R to Restart. Auto continue in %wait% seconds.   !CR!"
choice /c 0cr /t 1 /d 0 >nul
if errorlevel 3 echo(&goto pc
if errorlevel 2 echo(&goto bottom
set /a wait-=1
if %wait% equ 0 echo(&goto bottom
goto :waitLoop
```

Comment: Showing a timer is NOT necessary as long as the script will continue to run on it's own.. Your first comment sounds like what I need. I am a TOTAL newbie to writing code so I apologize for sounding dime but i don't know exactly how to write that. I know it replaces my time at the bottom... If I could press C or R or anything and have it either totally restart the script or move to a GO TO location it would be magic for us...

Comment: Thanks for suggesting using the Choices command, It took a little bit work but I've managed to get this working perfect for my needs now, So far.. I may reach out again if this doesn't work out.  Again, Thanks..     And thanks everyone else for trying to help me, I do appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

`timeout` does not return `errorlevel` if interrupted, so perhaps one way to solve this is to time `timeout`

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET /a "starttime=1%time:~-5,2%%time:~-2%"
timeout /t 30
SET /a "endtime=1%time:~-5,2%%time:~-2%"
IF %endtime% lss %starttime% SET /a endtime +=6000
SET /a elapsed=endtime - starttime
ECHO %elapsed%

GOTO :EOF
```

`elapsed` should contain the resultant time in tens-of-milliseconds. It's unlikely to be *exactly* 3000 for a 'no keypress' situation, but perhaps `if %elapsed% gtr 2980 echo no keypress` would suffice.

Note that I use a time format of `hh:mm:ss.hh` so if yours is different, you'd need to adjust the `time` substringing.

Since the target here is a timeout of about 30 seconds, the calculations can be performed on the seconds digits only. The values are accumulated as `1ss(.)hh` which ensures that there is not a leading zero so `set /a` will not attempt to enter `octal` mode. Since it's entirely possible that the end time will be in the next minute, the adding of 6000 compensates by adding-in the minute (6000 tens-of-milliseconds)

---

Since it seems to be necessary to build the entire batch,

```
@echo off

set /p username=ENTER LOGIN:

echo.

:pc

echo   1 -- Flats
echo   2 -- Simple Tabletop

set /P rmFunc="Enter a choice: "

:

for %%I in (1 x) do if #%rmFunc%==#%%I goto run%%I

:run1
set pc=300
goto begin

:run2
set pc=400
goto begin

:begin
set studio=TT
set computer=Handbag_1
set setnumber=
set studiosetnumber=%studio%_%setnumber%
set delay_swch=5
set delay_loop=30

:bottom

echo logged in as: %username%


SET /a "starttime=1%time:~-5,2%%time:~-2%"
timeout /t %delay_loop%
SET /a "endtime=1%time:~-5,2%%time:~-2%"
IF %endtime% lss %starttime% SET /a endtime +=6000
SET /a elapsed=endtime - starttime
if %elapsed% leq 2980 goto ???
GOTO BOTTOM
```

And - well there I'd have to leave it. You are setting `studio` and `setnumber` to constants within your code. Are these somehow related to "Process Class?" If you want to re-enter this data, then you'd need `???` above to be `begin` - but you'd need to `set /p` those values (which you haven't shown.) As for the file sweep - there's nowhere in your code that shows this filesweep happening. The modifications I have indicated will allow you to press any key to interrupt the 30-second `bottom` loop and re-enter the data.

Comment: Allow me to make this more clear. I work in a photo studio and we shoot different product all day. The script picks up files and moves them to our backup. We check for quality then move on. The script runs non sweeping folders every 30 sec. Each product has a different process class. You select this class at script start. Right now you have to close script and relaunch to change Process class. I need to be able to change the process class without having to shutdown script and, while it still continues it's normal folder sweep every 30 sec. If i could press a key and reset that would be great.